# Permanent data storage Azure VM

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine

In which folder (or location) should the data be stored in azure VM so that the data is not lost when VM is stopped(deallocated).

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a Windows VM, you can store data on the C: drive without losing data when the VM is deallocated. If you are looking to store a large amount of data, more than is available on the C: drive, you should look at creating an additional disk and attaching that to the VM.

On some VMs there is a temporary/ephemeral drive D: that will get deleted and reprovisioned when you stop(deallocate)/start or redeploy a VM. Do not use this drive for any data that you need to store permanently.

Comment: I am using Linux VM, where can I store in this.  Further, do I need to create backup on Azure portal?

Comment: For a Linux VM, your primary drive (/dev/sdb1) is mounted in "/". You can keep data anywhere on this drive without losing it when you stop/deallocate the VM. (The temporary drive /dev/sda1, if present,  is mounted under /mnt). You should backup data using the portal if it is important. Someone can still accidentally delete files/data, or a virus or ransomware could destroy your flies as well. Backup copies are always a good idea, unless the data can be easily recreated.